# How can I figure out when an user has last logged out? The user folder?

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles

In `C:\Users`, does the **date last modified** of the user's profile folder equate to the last day they logged out?

Comment: My user folder says that I have last modified it some hours ago, while I did my last reboot an half hour ago. No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the event viewer, go to the Security log in the Windows Logs. Here, look for events that are in the Task Category called Logoff. More specificall, events with ID 4634 are Logoff events.

You can create a new Custom View and filter by that event ID if you want to gather them together.

Answer (score 1):

No. Use the [Security event log](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742436.aspx) to check this instead.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess the folder's modified date does not correspond to the modified date of the folder's contents.

Comment: What event log in particular?  What event?